# I can't see on display screen what I actually snap by Nikon D5200

Tags: nikon

I recently purchased Nikon D5200 DSLR few weeks ago. So not aware with many of its settings.

Unlike my canon point & shoot cameras & my friend'd canon 600D, I can't actually see (on display screen) what I snap.

To be more elaborative, if I change some lighting conditions, result image is completely different than hat I actually see on display screen.

Plz tell me how I can do some settings for this.

Comment: To clarify, what you're saying is what you see on the live view screen is not the same as the resulting photo when you take the shot?

Comment: yes exactly!!!!

Comment: To clarify again, in what way is the final image different from what you see on the live view screen?

Comment: lighting or rather exposure.If i play with exposure I see different images snapped. But display live screen while taking the photo , always show same scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the option.

Menu > Shooting Menu > Movie Settings > Turn Manual movie settings on

And this video also explain the same.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PnaayF8nosk

Comment: This is also called simulator mode